# Fetching jQuery deferred for .html() on click

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred

I have a click handler that fetches an HTML string to inject through a template method. Right now it can't asynchronously return the HTML string from the callback, but I heard if I use jQuery defereds I may able to achieve this. However, I'm still not sure how I'd structure it after reading up on them.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
var api_response;

var templates = {

    inputSurveyList: function(){

        coApi.get_survey_list(function(data){
            api_response = data;
        });

        var buildSurveyList = function() {
            var element_list = '';
            $.each(api_response, function(index, survey){
                element_list += '<option value="' + survey.survey_id + '">' + survey.name + '</option>\n'
            });
            return element_list
        }

        var template = '<select class="input-survey-list" name="state">\n' + buildSurveyList() + '</select>';
        return template;
    }
}


$(foo).click(function(){
    $(bar).html(templates.inputSurveyList());
})
```

This is what the API methods look like:

```
var Request = function(method, parameters, callback, errback){
    var self = this;
    this.method = method;
    this.parameters = parameters;
    this.callback = callback;
    this.errback = errback;

    this.send = function(){
        $.ajax({
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify({method: self.method, params: self.parameters}),
            url: '/api',
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
                self.callback(data.response);
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                if (self.errback) {
                    self.errback(ajaxRequest);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}


var coAPI = {
    // Project Calls
    get_survey_list: function(callback, errback){
        var request = new Request('get_survey_list', {}, callback, errback);
        request.send();        
    },
    autocomplete_us_cities: function(term, callback, errback){
        var request = new Request('autocomplete_us_cities', {term: term}, callback, errback);
        request.send();
    },

}
```

Comment: Does your current code even work? it should be failing due to api_response still being undefined by the time buildSurveyList is called, unless you're using async:false and just not including it.

Comment: Correct-- the way its structured it fails because it's undefined. I wanted to know how to use deferreds to make it work but, didn't have a clue how to adapt it.

Answer (score 0):

Your $.ajax needs to return itself, so `return $.ajax({...})`, then in `get_survey_list: functi...` you need `return request.send()`

Now you can use it this way:

```
var templates = {

    inputSurveyList: function(callback){

        if (!callback) return; // if there's no callback, why generate template?

        var api_response = coApi.get_survey_list();

        var buildSurveyList = function(data) {
            var element_list = '';
            $.each(data, function(index, survey){
                element_list += '<option value="' + survey.survey_id + '">' + survey.name + '</option>\n'
            });
            return element_list
        }

        api_response.done(function(data){
            var template = '<select class="input-survey-list" name="state">\n' + buildSurveyList(data) + '</select>';
            callback.call(null,template);
        });
    }
}


$(foo).click(function(){
    templates.inputSurveyList(function(template){
        $(bar).html(template);
    });
});
```

You could modify it further to have inputSurveyList return it's own deferred object if you wish.